# Better alternative to using 'if (EXISTS path-to-file-or-directory)' in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a macro configured in CMake:

```
macro(set_up)
if (EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/buildinfo.cmake)
    include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/buildinfo.cmake)
else()
    if (EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tmp/build/buildinfo.cmake)
        include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tmp/build/buildinfo.cmake)
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Dependencies not linked." )
    endif()
endif()
endmacro()
```

The problem is that I am experiencing different behavior depending on which system and IDE I work on.
From the CMake website:

```
if(EXISTS path-to-file-or-directory)
True if the named file or directory exists. 
Behavior is well-defined only for explicit full paths  
(a leading ~/ is not expanded as a home directory and is considered a relative path). 
Resolves symbolic links, i.e. if the named file or directory is a symbolic link, 
returns true if the target of the symbolic link exists.
```

The main takeaway from the above is, "Behavior is well-defined only for explicit full paths".
Indeed, I am experiencing inconsistent behavior while using `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`, however if I hard code the path the loops works as expected.

My question is whether there is a better means of doing this file check with CMake, than to use `EXISTS`? I'd like to use `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` and not have to hard code the path.

Comment: `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` and `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` ***are*** absolute paths which means the whole path is absolute. The issue you encounter is unlikely to be the result of `if(EXISTS)` not working properly. One thing that seems weird is the fact that you're testing for the existance of a file in the build directory here. This means you're either possibly generating it during the cmake configuration or you're doing something wrong. Furthermore in general it's not a good idea to write stuff to the source directory which seems like something you do.

Comment: The problem could possibly be caused by the fact that the variables in the macro are evaluated at the point of the macro usage and not at the point of definition of the macro. This would explain, why hardcoding an absolute path works. Try adding some info to the error message: `message(FATAL_ERROR "Dependencies not linked: could not find files '${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/buildinfo.cmake' and '${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tmp/build/buildinfo.cmake'" )`

Comment: @fabian Thank you so much! You helped me resolve the issue.
`${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` was unexpectedly pointing to the `cmake-build-debug` directory (any idea why it's doing this?) ... if I use instead `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build` the issue is resolved.

Comment: If you do `cmake -S a -B b`, then `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` is the absolute path of `b` and `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is the absolute path to `a`. A proper explanation may require info about why you were expecting something different though. `cmake-build-debug` looks like some default choice though; If you leave the configuration up to the ide, it's probably the source of the issue. On the other hand it's definetly not a standard approach to rely on a specific choice of a build directory: Usually it's avoided for source and build trees to be potentially overlapping.